# One step list operation in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `A`. I am generating a new list by adding `1` to every element of the previous list and at the end, getting a combined list `B+C+D`. Is there a one step way to do this?

```
A=[12,8,4,0]
B=[i+1 for i in A]
C=[i+1 for i in B]
D=[i+1 for i in C]
print(B+C+D)
```

The current and expected output is

```
[13, 9, 5, 1, 14, 10, 6, 2, 15, 11, 7, 3]
```

Comment: The answers below ("Tom Karzes" and "nonlinear") are both very good. Though to be honest, your own code is already very clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
[i+j for i in range(1, 4) for j in A]
```

This produces:

```
[13, 9, 5, 1, 14, 10, 6, 2, 15, 11, 7, 3]
```

It can also be done with `itertools.product`, but in this case I don't think it buys you much:

```
[i+j for i, j in itertools.product(range(1, 4), A)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use numpy arrays:

```
A = np.array([12,8,4,0])
sol = np.concatenate((A+1, A+2, A+3))
```

The output is `[13, 9, 5, 1, 14, 10, 6, 2, 15, 11, 7, 3]` as expected.

Answer (score 3):

with walrus operator `:=`, you can achive this as

```
A=[12,8,4,0]
result = (B:= [i+1 for i in A]) + (C:= [i+1 for i in B]) + (D:= [i+1 for i in C])
print(result)
```

output

```
[13, 9, 5, 1, 14, 10, 6, 2, 15, 11, 7, 3]
```